# Calculating points for function with varying gradient

Tags: polynomials

I'm currently trying to automate the game stick hero. I've already worked out how to calculate the distance between the player and the next platform but I'm not sure how to program the "bridge". The bridge is just a stick thats getting bigger the longer I click or press on the screen. With various measurements I figured out that the growth of that stick is not linear and changes over time. Theoretically I could do measurements for every possible case, but that would be over 400 measurements I need to make. So I thought there has to be a better way to do this. I've already done a few measurements:

- 300ms - 167px
- 400ms - 226px
- 500ms - 275px
- 600ms - 334px
- 700ms - 384px
- 800ms - 462px

The growth also changes between my measurements:

- 325ms - 177px
- 350ms - 197px
- 375ms - 206px

So basically I have the number in pixels, and I need to calculate the required time with a non linear "growth" function. I already tried different sites where you can generate a polynomial function based on data you input but these don't work for the varying gradient.

Comment: Some valuable web reference on what is "the game stick hero" for beotians like me ?

Comment: in the end it doesnt really matter could have posted the question without that part I think. But if you want to have a look this is the app store link: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.stickhero) @JeanMarie